# Populating missing rows using SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am stuck at the following issue writing a SELECT SQL statement and was wondering if anyone can help. I have the following table with ProductID and Status fields:

| ProductID | Status |
| --- | --- |
| AP56546 |  |
| AP56546 | Shipped |
| AP56546 |  |
| AD92402 | Delayed |
| AD92402 |  |
| AD92402 |  |
| BE91455 |  |
| BE91455 |  |
| SL19423 |  |
| SL19423 |  |
| SL19423 |  |
| SL19423 | Expected |

How can I populate the Status for all Product with the same ID if even one of them has a status against it? If no Status exists for a certain product, then it can stay null. How can I do this using a SELECT statement? The expected result should be below (ProductID BE91455 is still null because there is no status against any of the rows where it occurs)

| ProductID | Status |
| --- | --- |
| AP56546 | Shipped |
| AP56546 | Shipped |
| AP56546 | Shipped |
| AD92402 | Delayed |
| AD92402 | Delayed |
| AD92402 | Delayed |
| BE91455 |  |
| BE91455 |  |
| SL19423 | Expected |
| SL19423 | Expected |
| SL19423 | Expected |
| SL19423 | Expected |

Thank you

Comment: Use a windowed `MAX`?

Comment: What's the expected result if a ProductID has different Status values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following using `max` partitioned by ProductId should work for you:

```
select ProductId, Max(Status) over(partition by ProductId) Status
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve desired results using below query:

***Sample Table***

```
CREATE TABLE TableData (
    ProductID varchar(10),
    Status varchar(10)
)
```

***Sample Data***

```
INSERT INTO TableData (ProductID, Status)
VALUES
    ('AP56546', ''),
    ('AP56546', 'Shipped'),
    ('AP56546', ''),
    ('AD92402', 'Delayed'),
    ('AD92402', ''),
    ('AD92402', ''),
    ('BE91455', ''),
    ('BE91455', ''),
    ('SL19423', ''),
    ('SL19423', ''),
    ('SL19423', ''),
    ('SL19423', 'Expected');
```

***Query***

```
WITH CTE AS (
 SELECT ProductID, Status 
  FROM TableData
  WHERE Isnull(Status,'') <> ''
  GROUP BY ProductID, Status
)
SELECT TableData.ProductID, COALESCE(CTE.Status, '') AS Status
FROM TableData
LEFT JOIN CTE
ON TableData.ProductID = CTE.ProductID;
```